# What is the purpose of the Test Plan's "State" field in TFS?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

What's the purpose of the test plan's State field?
Even if the value is set to Inactive it's still possible to run the test cases from that test plan.

I would like to prevent the testers to run test cases from test plans that are linked to past iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to prevent people to run test cases. Or to disable test plans. But the Inactive state does allow you to filter (and inactive plans are hidden by default in some views).

The reasoning behind this, I suspect, is that a test case can be re-used between different test plans and test suites and thus it makes no sense to "disable" a test case if one of these plans is in the past.

The purpose of the "Inactive" state is to allow you to filter. And to allow testers to differentiate current plans from older plans. They do not carry any weight otherwise.

When you create or manage your test plan you can select which sprint (Iteration Path) the Test Plan applies to.  The Test Hub will show the dates in the Test Plan screen, which may help your team decide whether it should run the tests.

Plus you can move these test plans to a Area that is not linked to your team. Any Test Plan that is not in the Team's list of area's is hidden in Web Access.

Comment: Our testers are using the web interface therefore is no way to limit them in using only the active test plans.

Comment: Great; that's what is looking for: move the test plan to other Area.